# Numerical Differentiation Given Set Of Values

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Given the values $f(0),f(h),f(2h)$ and $f'(h)$ , I need to find a numerical differentiation of highest approximation order to approximate $f''(0)$.
Usually I'd use Taylor expansion , but I need to find the highest order approximation and prove why is it actually the highest order approximation.

I'd be thankful if anyone could point me to the solution,thanks in advance !

Comment: Please write down the Taylor series for $f(h)-f(0)$, $f'(h)$ and $f(2h)-f(0)$ at the point $x=0$ and eliminate all lower derivatives except the second.

Comment: @LutzL , first of all thanks for the answer. The main problem I'm facing is proving the appriximation is of highest order, and I'd like to know how your suggestion helps proving it.

Comment: Is it understood that the approximation will be a linear combination of the values, or do you have to consider any smooth non-linear function with $f''(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}G(h,f(0), f(h), f(2h), f'(h))$?

Comment: @LutzL , I guess the appriximation will be a linear combination of the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you already did the Taylor series computation leading to
\begin{align}
&a_0f(0)+a_1f(h)+a_2f(2h)+b_1hf'(h)\\
&=
(a_0+a_1+a_2)f(0)+(a_1+2a_2+b_1)f'(0)h+\tfrac12(a_1+4a_2+2b_1)f''(0)h^2+\tfrac16(a_1+8a_2+3 b_1)f'''(0)h^3+\tfrac1{24}(a_1+16a_2+4b_1)f^{IV}(0)h^4+...\\
\end{align}
leading to the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0+a_1+a_2&=0\\
a_1+2a_2+b_1&=0\\
a_1+4a_2+2b_1&=2\\
a_1+8a_2+3 b_1&=0
\end{aligned}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{aligned}
a_1&=-2\\a_1+b_1&=4\\b_1&=6\\a_2&=-2\\a_0&=4
\end{aligned}
$$
That is
$$
f''(0)=2\frac{2f(0)-f(h)-f(2h)+3hf'(h)}{h^2}-\frac5{12}f^{IV}(0)h^2+O(h^3)
$$
Since there is no degree of freedom left over, the coefficient of the fourth derivative can not be set to zero without changing the coefficient of a lower derivative, it remains at $-\frac5{12}$. All combinations of derivative values up to the fourth derivative can naturally be achieved using polynomials, so the linear equations are all necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but I've got a question : why did you stop the Taylor series computation at the fourth derivative ? Why not at the third/fifth/sixth etc ?Moreover, why the order of approximation is the highest? Thank you once again.

Comment: Because with 4 values you get 4 coefficients in the linear combination and thus 4 equations that determine them. Under most conditions, i.e., in general asymmetric situations, these 4 linear equations result from the Taylor coefficients of order 0,1,2,3. Testing the 4th order Taylor coefficient shows that no miraculous cancellation occurs.